# Is it ethically correct to answer a question clarified by another user's comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

There is a question formulated in an extensive way, but due to language barriers not quite clear. The OP and another user have a conversation in the comments to clarify the question. After a couple of interactions and a day of time the question (and its answer) get quite obvious. Now a different user not involved in the discussion posts the correct answer. Is that correct behaviour?

Comment: Well, I'd say yes - if the person the OP was speaking to did not post an answer, it's fair game... At the end of the day, if the question deserves an answer, give it one, no matter who / how does it so long as you don't do it in a way that makes you the bad guy, I'd say a an hour is a justifiable amount of time to have waited to give the answer someone else got bit never posted

Comment: It is the most constructive way to use comments that I can think of.  You can credit the comment poster in your answer, but I personally don't think it is necessary.  You can flag the comment(s) as "no longer needed", not exactly necessary either.  I've seen users recommend CW, bah.  Have at it.

Comment: @Hans what do you mean by CW?

Comment: CW = community wiki.  A checkbox you can tick on your post.  You'll get no rep for the post and everybody can edit it.

Comment: If I see a question I want to answer, I answer it. They're far between these days so I'd grab the opportunity if I saw it. The person who helped the OP fix their question can of course also add their answer and the votes will decide the rest. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Just don't be the fastest gun. I always get a bit cranky if someone answers just 2 minutes after I get my clarification just while I'm writing up my own answer. It's still allowed though.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Indeed, nobody is hurt by hanging back for half an hour when you see things are being resolved through comments. But you know, the prime directive is to get good answers onto the site and help the future many. Ninja'ing someone is a bit of bad form, but I can't fault anyone for writing an answer no matter what their intentions are. I have upvoted quite a few such answers.

Comment: It'd be helpful if answers could comment on the need to paraphrase vs. copy/pasting comments into an answer.

Comment: @DrHopfen, I'm curious, why did you think this might be unethical?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes this is fine. There's no guarantee the commenter getting things clarified wants to or even *can* answer the question; I will sometimes do this for questions I have no intention of answering. If the person really wanted to answer, they will *probably* provide one as soon as they have a good idea of what the OP is asking.

As has been answered in the comments, if someone is feeling guilt about this, they can provide an answer but mark it as a Community Wiki answer (there's a checkbox for this at the bottom of the answer box when posting an answer), which indicates that the answer is "owned by the community" and open for wiki-style editing. This also prevents the person who posted it from receiving any reputation, privileges, or badges due to this answer (though it does still contribute to their answer count). This way there is no concern about someone unethically getting a leg up within the system.

Comment: I will accept the answer. I tried to formulate the question to not bias the answers/comments. I was the guy trying to clarify the question with the intention of answering. Just a couple of minutes after the question was clarified  the other guy answered within a few minutes. For the moment i felt a bit "betrayed" - the answer was correct and complete - so good for the guy who wrote it and earned the reputation.

Comment: I've seen way too many comments by people who don't write an answer to feel any guilt for not having been the first to respond. The downside of CW answers is the vast majority get little-to-no curation. If your answer goes beyond merely collecting answers from the comments from others, please take full credit. If anyone has a CW that is solely/mostly their own work, I'll be happy to change it back for them.

Comment: One aspect that hasn't been mentioned is that it's perfectly possible for a question to be unclear to one person (who then proceeds to ask clarifications from the OP) but be absolutely clear to another person, who can start typing an answer immediately without having to wait for said clarifications.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for "As has been answered in the comments".

Answer (score -10):

The question is just whether it's allowed by the forum rules.  If it is unethical, you need to the Help Center and try to get the rules changes.  My own take would be that it varies on a case-by-case basis and would be impossible to enforce objectively.

Comment: imo ethical and allowed are completely different things and q was if it would be ethically correct.